# R: mapply outputs matrix instead of function output

Tags: r, mapply

In R, I have a function (`plot.volcano.norm`) that plots data from a data frame with ggplot2. It requires two inputs: The data frame with the data and a character vector. Because I have multiple data frames that I want to plot data from, I have multiple data frames in a list (`data.list`), as well as a vector (`title.list`) that contains character elements that are needed for the function to work properly (one for each data frame).

When I run the following:

```r
plot.volcano.norm(data.list[[1]],title.list[1])
```

I get the correct plot for the first data frame in `data.list`. Now, I want to run the function for *all* of the elements in the `data.list`. For this, I used

```r
mapply(plot.volcano.norm, data.list, title.list)
```

But now the output is a matrix:

```
            [,1]    [,2]   
data        List,12 List,16
layers      List,3  List,3 
scales      ?       ?      
mapping     List,2  List,2 
theme       List,93 List,93
coordinates ?       ?      
facet       ?       ?      
plot_env    ?       ?      
labels      List,6  List,6 
guides      List,2  List,2
```

I have checked `?mapply`, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I get `mapply` to work properly? Or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Welcome and thanks for sharing your output. It would also be helpful to have a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and your desired output also helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` which outputs a matrix. Try:

```
mapply(plot.volcano.norm, data.list, title.list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `Map`

```
Map(plot.volcano.norm, data.list, title.list)
```